# How to remove markups of 'div' and 'span' from the billing info displayed through token

Tags: rules, commerce, tokens

I am trying to add token for billing information in order confirmation email . The token does its job but also displays markups of 'div' and 'span'. Whats surprises me is all the other tokens in the same email works fine and doesn't display any mark ups, however the issue is only with the token of field type: 'Postal Address' within the billing information profile

These are the two tokens I have used:

[message:message-commerce-order:commerce_customer_billing]

[message:message-commerce-order:commerce-customer-billing:commerce_customer_address]

I added these tokens to email through admin->structure->message type, since I am also using the following three modules: Commerce Message, Message Notify and Message

Any help on how to display complete billing info without markups, as entered in the built in field: 'Postal address' will be highly appreciated. Tried all the checklists in admin->configuration->text format, but no luck

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the content of tokens you could try using the Token Function module: http://www.drupal.org/project/token_function

With this module you can write a simple function to alter the content of a token (or use one of the few existing functions).

I hope this helps.